# ¿Cómo puedo formar la figura de una cruz con asteriscos en un array bidimensional? JAVA

Tags: java

¡Hola!, el problema que me dejaron en la universidad es el siguiente:

Elaborar el programa que reciba dos índices
(dados por el usuario) posteriormente deberá
imprimir un arreglo bidimensional con una cruz
en el centro.

Mi problema es que si por ejemplo el usuario en el primer índice pone 5 y en el segundo índice pone 2 (algo así char arr[][] = new char[5][2]), la cruz se dibuja mal, por lo que llegue a conclusión de que si pones números primos o pares en ambos índices la figura se dibuja bien, si alguien tiene o sabe de alguna solución estaría genial que me ayudaran :')

**MI CÓDIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE**

**MAIN**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MetodoCruz m = new MetodoCruz();
        m.cruz();
    }
}
```

**METODO QUE DIBUJA LA CRUZ**

```
public class MetodoCruz {
    public void cruz(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i1, i2;
        char arr[][];
        System.out.println("Ingrese el indice 1: ");
        i1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el indice 2: ");
        i2 = input.nextInt();
        arr = new char[i1][i2];
        System.out.println();
        if (arr.length%2==0){
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    if (i == arr.length/2 || j == arr[0].length/2 || j == (arr[0].length/2)-1 || i == (arr.length/2)-1){
                        arr[i][j] = '*';
                    }else {
                        arr[i][j] = ' ';
                    }
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    if (i == arr.length/2 || j == arr[0].length/2){
                        arr[i][j] = '*';
                    }else {
                        arr[i][j] = ' ';
                    }
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SALIDA CON 2 INDICES PARES**

```
Ingrese el indice 1: 
6
Ingrese el indice 2: 
4

  * *   
  * *   
* * * * 
* * * * 
  * *   
  * *
```

**SALIDA CON 2 INDICES IMPARES**

```
Ingrese el indice 1: 
5
Ingrese el índice 2: 
3

  *   
  *   
* * * 
  *   
  *
```

**SALIDA CON 1 INDICE PAR Y OTRA IMPAR**

```
Ingrese el indice 1: 
4
Ingrese el índice 2: 
3

* *   
* * * 
* * * 
* *
```

**ESTE ES UN ESQUEMA DEL QUE BASE MI LOGICA PARA HACER EL EJERCICIO Y DEL COMO DEBERIA QUEDAR (PERO NO ME SALE :'D)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]